# Merge secondlife, lsl and linden-scripting-language tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The scripting language for Second Life is called "Linden Scripting Language" aka "lsl". There are a number of questions tagged [linden-scripting-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linden-scripting-language), a number tagged [secondlife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/secondlife) and a number tagged [lsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lsl). I submit that the only questions about Second Life appropriate to Stack Overflow are probably about Linden Scripting Language, so merging [secondlife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/secondlife) into [linden-scripting-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linden-scripting-language) is probably a no-brainer. Unfortunately "lsl" can also mean "lua scripting library", so that might require some looking, although I've found a number of questions that have two or even three of these days.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm looking at it, some of the "secondlife" ones are not Linden Scripting Language related.

Answer (score 4):

I went through all the questions tagged "lsl", and all but one were about Linden Scripting Language so I retagged them. The one that was about Lua Scripting Library, I attempted to retag, and there was no existing lua-scripting-library tag. I copied the part of the lsl tag wiki that pertained to Lua Scripting Library to the new tag's tag wiki.